# Xcode schemes: One project which selects either iOS or Mac OS X

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, libraries, xcode-scheme

I am trying to build a library for inclusion in other iOS/Mac OS X projects. I currently have two separate projects that I switch between to build the library. I would like to have one project and two different schemes so that another person in my team can just change the scheme and get the kind of library they want.
I would like to avoid having to manually add a new file to each separate project individually when I need to do so. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open your iOS project.
2. Choose File > New > Target… from the menu bar.
3. Click Framework & Library in the OS X section.
4. Choose the Cocoa Library target.
5. Enter a name for the OS X version of the library.  It must be different than the iOS library name.  Example: “MyLibraryOSX”.
6. Maybe change the type to Static.
7. Click Finish.
8. Select your project itself in the Project Navigator.
9. Click on the new OS X library target in the TARGETS section.
10. Click on the Build Phases tab.
11. Open the Compile Sources section.
12. Note that Xcode automatically created a `.m` file with the same name as the OS X library target.  You may wish to delete this from your project.
13. Add your library sources to the Compile Sources section.

Xcode normally creates a scheme for the new target automatically.  If you have turned “Autocreate schemes” off for this project, you need to choose Product > Manage Schemes… and create (or ask Xcode to autocreate) the scheme for the new target.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response this did what I needed to do.